# Resize image from base64_encode

Tags: php, image, base64, encode, image-resizing

My image file size is 800x600 and I want to resize this 800x600 to 400x300 then save both images(800x600 and 400x300) in the database base64_encode format. I can save in database first image (800x600) but how to convert a second image (400x300) in base64_encode format and save in database? I don't want to use two input fields. I think one input field enough for that.

```
$image              = ($_FILES["my_image"]["name"]);
$theme_image        = ($_FILES["my_image"]["tmp_name"]);
$bin_string         = file_get_contents("$theme_image"); 
$theme_image_enc    = base64_encode($bin_string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a little script for create the new image from the first one and make the base64_encode on it

```
$WIDTH                  = 400; // The size of your new image
$HEIGHT                 = 300;  // The size of your new image
$QUALITY                = 100; //The quality of your new image
$DESTINATION_FOLDER = DependOfYourRepository; // The folder of your new image

// The directory where is your image
$filePath = DependOfYourRepository; 

// This little part under depend if you wanna keep the ratio of the image or not
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filePath);
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
if ($WIDTH/$HEIGHT > $ratio_orig) {
    $WIDTH = $HEIGHT*$ratio_orig;
} else {
    $HEIGHT = $WIDTH/$ratio_orig;
}

// The function using are different for png, so it's better to check
if ($file_ext == "png") {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
} else {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
}

// I create the new image with the new dimension and maybe the new quality
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor($WIDTH, $HEIGHT);
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopyresampled($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $WIDTH, $HEIGHT, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagedestroy($image);
imagejpeg($bg, $DESTINATION_FOLDER.$filename, $QUALITY);
$bin_string_little = file_get_contents($DESTINATION_FOLDER.$filename); 
// I remove the image created because you just wanna save the base64 version
unlike($DESTINATION_FOLDER.$filename);
imagedestroy($bg);
$theme_image_enc_little =  base64_encode($bin_string_little); 
// And now do what you want with the result
```

**EDIT 1**

It's possible to do it without using a directory for the second image but it's quite tricky.

```
$theme_image_little = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($theme_image_enc));
$image_little = imagecreatetruecolor($WIDTH, $HEIGHT);
// $org_w and org_h depends of your image, in your case, i guess 800 and 600
imagecopyresampled($image_little, $theme_image_little, 0, 0, 0, 0, $WIDTH, $HEIGHT, $org_w, $org_h);

// Thanks to Michael Robinson
// start buffering
ob_start();
imagepng($image_little);
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$theme_image_enc_little = base64_encode($contents):
```

Comment: my file is directly saved in database in base64_encode format. I dont want to use destination folder. is this possible without using destination path second image save in database ?

Comment: Thanks, is possible to make the second image size smaller like 15kb. Because second image will use for thumbnail.